# Why does python thread still run while waiting?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm curious as to why the while loop in below code still runs after I told it to wait on a event object.

```
import threading, time
msg = threading.Event()

def sec():
    print  "second thread starting now.."
    counter = 0

    while True:
    #while msg.isSet():
        print "hello"
        print counter
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(3)
        msg.wait()

secThread = threading.Thread(target = sec)
secThread.start()

print "a"
msg.set()
time.sleep(5)
print "b"
msg.set()
```

And I get the following output

```
second thread starting now..a

hello
0
hello
1
b
hello
2
hello
3
....
(keeps going)
```

I can fix it with the commented out while loop, but I'm curious as to why it still ran. The main thread is done running so nothing should be setting the threading event to allow the second thread to run.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `msg` is set (you set it), the loop does not need to wait. If you want to make the loop wait, call `clear` on the event. You can make the loop call `msg.clear()` after `msg.wait` returns if you wish.

Comment: Got it. I made the mistake of thinking that "wait" would reset the flag back, but it doesn't. To reset the flag back, I should use clear instead like you said.